# Increment array when cloning jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/stomp/a8vjg/

Everything works well except I need the name of the select field to be extras[0], then extras[1] for the next one added and so on..

Can anybody help?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First you should name your select element with "extras" only ...

```
<select name="extras">
```

Then get it using

```
elemenets = $('[name=extras]')
```

it will be an Array you can access by extras[0] , extras[1] , ..... etc

Answer (score 0):

You need sth like this when cloning:

```
case "add":
            var cnt=jqEl.parent().siblings().size();
            var cloned=tag.clone();
               $(cloned).find("input").val("")
                   .end()
                   .find('select').attr('name','extra['+cnt+']');

            tag.after(cloned);
            break;
```

check the working [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/V3vTc/3/) (might be duplicates if you remove and add)

No duplicates [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3vTc/4/)  (serial number could not be ensured if you delete a node)

So the perfect solution could be adding the ids on [Save] button here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/V3vTc/5/)

```
function save(e) {
        multiTags.find("select").each(function(i){
            $(this).attr('name','extras['+i+']');
        });

        var tags = multiTags.find("input.tag").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(',');
        alert(tags);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This sometimes creates duplicates if you add/remove items a lot

Comment: what you want when a node is removed , reset the names ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
case "add":
                var newTag = tag.clone();
                var i = $("#multi").find("select").length;
                console.log(i);
                 newTag.find("select").attr("name", 'extras['+i+']');              
            tag.after(newTag.find("input").val("").end());
            break;
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8vjg/15/)

Comment: This sometimes creates duplicates if you add/remove items a lot